# Deploy app to many iPhones from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I created an app, that when I deploy it in an iphone(3g), uploads fine (also submited this app to itunes connect for free), but when I connect another device to test it, I get

```
Cant run "appName" on the Iphone "my iphone"
the iphone "my iphone" doesn't have the provisioning profile with which the 
application  was signed, click install and run...
```

but if I do, i get

```
Error from debugger" the program being debugged is not being run
```

how to make the xcode recognize this second iphone?
if I create a new project, then I can try this new project in my second iphone, so what to change to make it work??, I have tried changing signing options to no avail 
;(

what to do please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add uID of iPhone / iPad to itunesconnect and then probably download again the certificate (of the app provisionning).

The error means the device isn't authorized to have an application installed depending what you said to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add udid of that device to your provision profile.